# listbox filter in msaccess form

Tags: ms-access, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox added to my form which allows me to quickly jump between entries in my database.
It uses the tblProjectCoreData as a source and just displays 4 rows: ProjectID, ProjectName, Product and Customer. I want to filter the list and tried using a button:

`Private Sub butFilter()
    DoCmd.GoToControl "Product"
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub`

This however did not work. Can someone kindly help me out?

EDIT:

I had moderate success with the following function:

```
Private Sub FilterBy_Change()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT listbox001 Product FROM tblProjectCoreData WHERE Product Like '" & Me.FilterBy.Text & "*' ORDER BY Product"
    Me.listbox001.RowSource = sql
End Sub
```

This then filters the entries in the table based on what i entered into the "FilterBy" Textbox. However, it doesnt allow me to jump to the entry in the database and just filters the list.

Comment: What does 'did not work' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens. Did you mean 4 fields? acCmdFilterMenu opens column quick filter and has nothing to do with a listbox.

Comment: yea, i wanted to use the column quick filter menu, because i naively thought this would also work on listboxes. I have since edited my question with a different function which "somehow" works. I hope this makes things clearer

Comment: Revised code employs what is know as conditional or cascading combobox or listbox. A very common topic. Yes, filtering listbox does not apply filter to form. That requires some more code to set form Filter property or go to a record. Another common topic. Also, should not use Text property. You want the Value of textbox.